# Swift - Writing a generic HTTP request

Tags: swift, oop, generics, inheritance, urlsession

So I am trying to retrieve some data using some normal HTTP requests with Swift's new `Decodable` protocol.

The problem is that I am finding that I am writing very similar code again and again (create a URL session, decode the data, completion handler etc).

I am thinking of simplifying using generics or inheritance but not sure how I can initialize 'generic objects'.

Current code:

```swift
var response = TypeAResponse()

if let url = URL(string: urlName) {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in

        if let data = data {

            do {
                response = try JSONDecoder().decode(TypeAResponse.self, from: data)
                completion(true, TypeAResponse.items)
            } catch let parseError {
                print("parseError: \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false, TypeAResponse.items)
            }

        } else {
            print("Error: Data not found")
            completion(false, TypeAResponse.items)
        }
    }

    task.resume()

} else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    completion(false, TypeAResponse.items)
}
```

But TypeAResponse has a different structure to say a TypeBResponse - all they share is the 'items' attribute.

Could do something like

```
    func get<T>(generalType: T, completion: GeneralRequest){
        //but how would you initialise generalType?
        //cannot do something like
        var response = T()

    }
```

For reference, TypeAResponse and TypeBResponse may be something like:

```
struct TypeAResponse: Decodable {
    items: [Track]?
}

struct Track: Decodable {
    //for example
    var name: String?
}

struct TypeBResponse: Decodable {
    items: [Playlist]?
}

struct Playlist: Decodable {
    var name, id, description: String?
}
```

API Responses:

Please see Spotify Web API reference - https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist/

(specifically 'Get a User's Playlists' and 'Get a Playlist's Tracks')

Comment: please include your class declarations for `TypeAResponse` and `TypeBResponse`

Comment: those are invalid `struct` definitions. what is the type of `items`?

Comment: What's the benefit of using one rather than the other?

Comment: You can use a `JSONDecoder` on a string object, assuming the JSON fields match the type and name of the `Decodable` structure exactly.

Comment: The point I'm trying to highlight is that they're different types. Wanted to avoid pasting a lot of unnecessary detail. I'll add them now

Comment: The type and name of each property in a `Decodable` structure is extremely important in properly decoding it from a JSON string

Comment: Now what does your response string look like?

Comment: I can run this just fine and it works: `let jsonString = "{ \"items\": [ { \"height\": 0 } ] }"; if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) { let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TypeAResponse.self, from: data); print(response?.items ?? "fail") }`

Comment: I really recommend to start by reading Rob Napier's blog articles https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol

Comment: Yes I thought a protocol could be what I need here. New to Swift so have never really explored these before. I'll have a look at the article

Comment: Yes the code works, but I want to be able to write a general GET method that can parse and decode a response for a given model; one that I can use multiple times

Comment: the response object from Spotify does not have a `items` property but it does have an `items` key nested within an object under `tracks`

Comment: Sorry forgot to change the last line - should be fine now.

Comment: @Sulthan Rob Napier's blog article is exactly what I needed! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're certainly on a fine track here. Always good to start with concrete code and then see how to make it more generic. To your specific case, as you ask "how would you initialize generalType?" That's exactly what a protocol allows you to do. So following along your approach, you could write something like (I haven't tested this; it might have some syntax errors):

```
func get<T: Decodable>(generalType: T, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void {

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            let err = error ?? ... some default error ...
            completion(.failure(err))
            return
        }

        let result = Result {
            // You know you can call `decode` with it because it's Decodable
            try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        }
        completion(result)                     
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The series [Start With A Protocol](https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol) may be of help (thanks to those who mentioned it). It goes into much more depth on this problem. But for simple applications, this function may be all you need, and you should avoid adding more complexity until it's useful to you.

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `Result<T, Error>`.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your fields must **exactly** match the name of the fields in the JSON string you are decoding. Hope the following short example helps. Depending on how much you actually want to decode the following would be able to decode a response object from Spotify:

Assuming your response object is the following (taken from [Spotify's example](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist/)):

```
{
  "collaborative" : false,
  "description" : "Having friends over for dinner? Here´s the perfect playlist.",
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC"
  },
  "followers" : {
    "href" : null,
    "total" : 143350
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC",
  "id" : "59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC",
  "images" : [ {
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/68b6a65573a55095e9c0c0c33a274b18e0422736"
  } ],
  "name" : "Dinner with Friends",
  "owner" : {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify",
    "id" : "spotify",
    "type" : "user",
    "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify"
  },
  "public" : null,
  "snapshot_id" : "bNLWdmhh+HDsbHzhckXeDC0uyKyg4FjPI/KEsKjAE526usnz2LxwgyBoMShVL+z+",
  "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC/tracks",
    "items" : [ {
      "added_at" : "2014-09-01T04:21:28Z",
      "added_by" : {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify",
        "id" : "spotify",
        "type" : "user",
        "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify"
      },
      "is_local" : false,
      "track" : {
        "album" : {
          "album_type" : "single",
          "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "UY" ],
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563"
          },
          "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563",
          "id" : "5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563",
          "images" : [ {
            "height" : 640,
            "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/47421900e7534789603de84c03a40a826c058e45",
            "width" : 640
          }, {
            "height" : 300,
            "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/0d447b6faae870f890dc5780cc58d9afdbc36a1d",
            "width" : 300
          }, {
            "height" : 64,
            "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/d926b3e5f435ef3ac0874b1ff1571cf675b3ef3b",
            "width" : 64
          } ],
          "name" : "I'm Not The Only One",
          "type" : "album",
          "uri" : "spotify:album:5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563"
        },
        "artists" : [ {
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI"
          },
          "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI",
          "id" : "2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI",
          "name" : "Sam Smith",
          "type" : "artist",
          "uri" : "spotify:artist:2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI"
        } ],
        "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "IE", "IS", "IT", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "RO", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "UY" ],
        "disc_number" : 1,
        "duration_ms" : 204732,
        "explicit" : false,
        "external_ids" : {
          "isrc" : "GBUM71403920"
        },
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb",
        "id" : "4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb",
        "name" : "I'm Not The Only One - Radio Edit",
        "popularity" : 45,
        "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/dd64cca26c69e93ea78f1fff2cc4889396bb6d2f",
        "track_number" : 1,
        "type" : "track",
        "uri" : "spotify:track:4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb"
      }
    }],
    "limit" : 100,
    "next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC/tracks?offset=100&limit=100",
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 105
  },
  "type" : "playlist",
  "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC"
}
```

```swift
struct Playlist: Decodable {
    var collaborative: Bool?
    var description: String?
    var external_urls: [String: String]?
    var followers: FollowerData?
    var href, id: String?
    var images: [Image]?
    var name: String?
    var owner: User?
    var `public`: String?
    var snapshot_id: String?
    var tracks: Track?
    var type: String?
    var uri: String?
}

struct FollowerData: Decodable {
    var href: String?
    var total: Int?
}

struct User: Decodable {
    var external_urls: [String: String]?
    var href, id, name, type, uri: String?
}

struct Track: Decodable {
    var href: String?
    var items: [TrackItem]?
    var limit: Int?
    var next: String?
    var offset: Int?
    var previous: String?
    var total: Int?
}

struct TrackItem: Decodable {
    var added_at: String?
    var added_by: User?
    var is_local: Bool?
    var track: TrackDetails?
}

struct TrackDetails: Decodable {
    var album: Album?
    var artists: [User]?
    var available_markets: [String]?
    var disc_number: Int?
    var duration_ms: Int?
    var explicit: Bool?
    var external_ids: [String: String]?
    var external_urls: [String: String]?
    var href, id, name: String?
    var popularity: Int?
    var preview_url: String?
    var track_number: Int?
    var type: String?
    var uri: String?
}

struct Album: Decodable {
    var album_type: String?
    var available_markets: [String]?
    var external_urls: [String: String]?
    var href, id: String?
    var images: [Image]?
}

struct Image: Decodable {
    var width, height: Int?
    var url: String?
}

let jsonString = "{ \"collaborative\" : false, \"description\" : \"Having friends over for dinner? Here´s the perfect playlist.\", \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC\" }, \"followers\" : { \"href\" : null, \"total\" : 143350 }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC\", \"id\" : \"59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC\", \"images\" : [ { \"url\" : \"https://i.scdn.co/image/68b6a65573a55095e9c0c0c33a274b18e0422736\" } ], \"name\" : \"Dinner with Friends\", \"owner\" : { \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify\" }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify\", \"id\" : \"spotify\", \"type\" : \"user\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:user:spotify\" }, \"public\" : null, \"snapshot_id\" : \"bNLWdmhh+HDsbHzhckXeDC0uyKyg4FjPI/KEsKjAE526usnz2LxwgyBoMShVL+z+\", \"tracks\" : { \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC/tracks\", \"items\" : [ { \"added_at\" : \"2014-09-01T04:21:28Z\", \"added_by\" : { \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify\" }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify\", \"id\" : \"spotify\", \"type\" : \"user\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:user:spotify\" }, \"is_local\" : false, \"track\" : { \"album\" : { \"album_type\" : \"single\", \"available_markets\" : [ \"AD\", \"AR\", \"AT\", \"AU\", \"BE\", \"BG\", \"BO\", \"BR\", \"CH\", \"CL\", \"CO\", \"CR\", \"CY\", \"CZ\", \"DK\", \"DO\", \"EC\", \"EE\", \"ES\", \"FI\", \"FR\", \"GB\", \"GR\", \"GT\", \"HK\", \"HN\", \"HU\", \"IE\", \"IS\", \"IT\", \"LI\", \"LT\", \"LU\", \"LV\", \"MC\", \"MT\", \"MY\", \"NI\", \"NL\", \"NO\", \"NZ\", \"PA\", \"PE\", \"PH\", \"PL\", \"PT\", \"PY\", \"RO\", \"SE\", \"SG\", \"SI\", \"SK\", \"SV\", \"TR\", \"TW\", \"UY\" ], \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"https://open.spotify.com/album/5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563\" }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563\", \"id\" : \"5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563\", \"images\" : [ { \"height\" : 640, \"url\" : \"https://i.scdn.co/image/47421900e7534789603de84c03a40a826c058e45\", \"width\" : 640 }, { \"height\" : 300, \"url\" : \"https://i.scdn.co/image/0d447b6faae870f890dc5780cc58d9afdbc36a1d\", \"width\" : 300 }, { \"height\" : 64, \"url\" : \"https://i.scdn.co/image/d926b3e5f435ef3ac0874b1ff1571cf675b3ef3b\", \"width\" : 64 } ], \"name\" : \"I'm Not The Only One\", \"type\" : \"album\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:album:5GWoXPsTQylMuaZ84PC563\" }, \"artists\" : [ { \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"https://open.spotify.com/artist/2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI\" }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI\", \"id\" : \"2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI\", \"name\" : \"Sam Smith\", \"type\" : \"artist\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:artist:2wY79sveU1sp5g7SokKOiI\" } ], \"available_markets\" : [ \"AD\", \"AR\", \"AT\", \"AU\", \"BE\", \"BG\", \"BO\", \"BR\", \"CH\", \"CL\", \"CO\", \"CR\", \"CY\", \"CZ\", \"DK\", \"DO\", \"EC\", \"EE\", \"ES\", \"FI\", \"FR\", \"GB\", \"GR\", \"GT\", \"HK\", \"HN\", \"HU\", \"IE\", \"IS\", \"IT\", \"LI\", \"LT\", \"LU\", \"LV\", \"MC\", \"MT\", \"MY\", \"NI\", \"NL\", \"NO\", \"NZ\", \"PA\", \"PE\", \"PH\", \"PL\", \"PT\", \"PY\", \"RO\", \"SE\", \"SG\", \"SI\", \"SK\", \"SV\", \"TR\", \"TW\", \"UY\" ], \"disc_number\" : 1, \"duration_ms\" : 204732, \"explicit\" : false, \"external_ids\" : { \"isrc\" : \"GBUM71403920\" }, \"external_urls\" : { \"spotify\" : \"https://open.spotify.com/track/4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb\" }, \"href\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb\", \"id\" : \"4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb\", \"name\" : \"I'm Not The Only One - Radio Edit\", \"popularity\" : 45, \"preview_url\" : \"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/dd64cca26c69e93ea78f1fff2cc4889396bb6d2f\", \"track_number\" : 1, \"type\" : \"track\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:track:4i9sYtSIlR80bxje5B3rUb\" } }], \"limit\" : 100, \"next\" : \"https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC/tracks?offset=100&limit=100\", \"offset\" : 0, \"previous\" : null, \"total\" : 105 }, \"type\" : \"playlist\", \"uri\" : \"spotify:user:spotify:playlist:59ZbFPES4DQwEjBpWHzrtC\"}"
if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    let playlist = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Playlist.self, from: data)
    print(playlist ?? "fail")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply

But I was looking more for a way to write a generic get request so that I wouldn't it and all its error handling all over again every time I wanted to decode to a different model. Will look into protocols; as suggested by comment above

Comment: You can get the idea from my code how much further down you would have to go, but the `Playlist` structure above would be able to parse a Spotify response successfully

Comment: @Vedant I went ahead and wrote all of the `Decodable` structures necessary to parse a playlist response from Spotify

Comment: If you want a generic JSON object as a `[String:Any]` dictionary just use [`JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject)

Comment: Thanks for the help